# Load GIF From URL

Tags: android, android-glide

I tried to get [this GIF](http://artfcity.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tumblr_osmx1ogeOD1r2geqjo1_540.gif) from a URL like this:

```
 Glide.with(context)
                .load("http://artfcity.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tumblr_osmx1ogeOD1r2geqjo1_540.gif")
                .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageViewBaby) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable drawable, GlideAnimation anim) {
                        super.onResourceReady(drawable, anim);
                        imageViewBaby.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        imageViewBaby.invalidate();
                        imageViewBaby.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
```

But the GIF will not move or start. It's just like an image! How to solve this issue?

Comment: I usually loads GIFs into WebViews, don't know another component that supports the animation

Comment: hmmmm ,, ok i will tried but do you know how to make web view circle ?

Comment: WebView is a View, you can make the same thing you did for ImageView

Comment: but i tried ,, to make it circle but i failed :(

Comment: @MeladDavid try my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this**

Add dependency

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
```

Gif Loading

```
    Glide.with(this)
      .load("http://artfcity.com/wp-
      content/uploads/2017/07/tumblr_osmx1ogeOD1r2geqjo1_540.gif")
            .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .into(imageView);
```

See this https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2471

Comment: i try it now and user     compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.0'
but its not working same issue!!

Comment: same issue means image not loading?

Comment: implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'

Comment: Error:(52, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:/Users/malik/Desktop/Rawhi android repo/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: when i add the dependency !

Comment: What is your grade version 4.1?

Comment: my gradle : 2.3.1

Comment: Try to update ..or instead of implementation use compile

Comment: In my device GIF loading try to update 4.4.0..happy coding

Comment: Please agree my answer if it's helpful

Comment: Happy to help you

Comment: how to make image view circle ! i tried many library but the gif stop ! how i can make image view circle and load gif ?

Answer (score 0):

As android doesnot support gif files, you can use webview to display the gif file.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `.asGif()` to load gif images inside your `ImageView`:

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(gifUrl)
            .asGif()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).override(200, 200)
            .into(((GifViewHolder) holder).gifImageView);
```