# Is it possible to show GIF and also JPG image on the same adapter using Glide?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

Is it possible to show GIF and also JPG image on the same adapter using Glide? If it is possible, then how code looks like in Glide?

Comment: Do you know the type of file when loading?

Comment: you need put condition according to it

Comment: @SaikrishnaRajaraman the images load from URL

Comment: If file is JPG simply put it and if file is GIF use glide. Just use this condition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013012/load-gif-from-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
String str = "image or gif url";
        if (str.contains(".gif")){
            Glide.with(this)
                    .asGif()
                    .load(str)
                    .into(imgeview);
        }else{
            Glide
                    .with(this)
                    .load(str)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(myImageView);
        }
```

Comment: Why not `str.endsWith(".gif")`? what if a file is named `file.gif.png`?

Comment: @Deadbeef its consider as png file so git is not woking